# Минимизация CSS

Tags: веб-программирование, css

Всем, Здравствуйте!

Как минимизировать CSS, как здесь? - http://sidigital.co/public/css/compiled.css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь онлайн сервисами для оптимизации CSS. Вот только некоторые из них:

1. [cssdrive.com](http://cssdrive.com) CSS Compressor — работает в 2 режимах: обычный и продвинутый. Вы можете выбрать один из трех уровней сжатия. Режим "Normal" должен хорошо работать в большинстве случаев, создавая оптимальный баланс между ними.
2. http://www.cleancss.com – CSS форматирование и оптимизатор на основе csstidy доступна на английском, немецком и французском языках.
3. [CSS Compressor](http://www.csscompressor.com/)  - можно выбрать 4 уровня сжатия.
4. [CSS Optimizer](http://www.cssoptimiser.com/)  - Оптимизация CSS указав URL адрес css-файла, загрузив файл с локального компьютера или непосредственно введя CSS код в форму.
5. [codebeautifier.com](http://codebeautifier.com)  - CSS Compressor  на основе CSSTidy
6. [askapache.com](http://askapache.com)  - данный сервис использует часть порта JavaScript из YUI Compressor, и часть W3 CSS Validator. Вы можете загрузить CSS файл, указать URL CSS-файла, или просто вставить CSS код в форму.
7. [iceyboard.no-ip.org](http://iceyboard.no-ip.org) CSS Compressor - Вы можете загрузить файл, указать URL CSS-файла или вставить CSS код. Хорошие варианты сжатия.
8. [ebiene.de](http://ebiene.de) – сервис для сжатия JavaScript и CSS файлов. Вы можете выбрать между базовым сжатием и сильным.
9. [pagecolumn.com](http://pagecolumn.com) – Сжатие CSS, возможность поиска и удаления неиспользуемых классов и ID в CSS (опционально).
10. [Pingates.com](http://Pingates.com) -  Вы можете указать URL CSS файла или вставить CSS код.