# Вопрос почему position зипись делают на 2 строках

Tags: css

При написании свойства position:absolute or position:relative не важно - 
запись ведеться на двух строках

```
position: relative;
top: 100px; left: 100px;
```

а вот так редко кто запись делает

```
position: relative; top: 100px; left: 100px;
```

Почему так? Это просто потому что так удобно или есть какая то польза от этой записи?

Comment: Или в одну строчку или в разных вообще пишут.

Comment: обычно в три строки вообще,

Comment: Вопрос почему так??

Comment: @soledar10: Причины у всех сугубо личные. Кто-то старается чтобы код выглядел компактно, кому-то важна хорошая читаемость, а кто-то пишет как попало. На конечный результат запись в данном случае не влияет никак.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо всем за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобное написание влияет только на [вес css файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/258323/web-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-css) и визуальное восприятие при верстке.